# How to assigning an Action of "GenericType" in a Action of a base type of the "GenericType"?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I need assign an `Action` of "GenericType" in a `Action` of a base type of the "GenericType".
Therefore, I will have several actions and each of a different `ModelMapNode` type.

```
public class ModelMapNode { }

public class ModelMapNode<TModelMap> : ModelMapNode { }

public class Class1
{
    private List<Action<ModelMapNode>> Actions { get; set; }

    public void AddAction<T>(Action<ModelMapNode<T>> childConfigurer)
    {
        this.Actions.Add((Action<ModelMapNode>)childConfigurer);
    }
}
```

This type cast does not work.

Comment: Can all this be static by any chance ?

Comment: @vittore Why would you want it to be static?

Comment: because there is a trick with static properties of inner generic classes that will allow to do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643294/how-to-assigning-an-action-of-generictype-in-a-action-of-a-base-type-of-the-g#comment30902101_20643349), you know that an `Action<ModelMapNode<T>>` object cannot be safely cast to a `(Action<ModelMapNode>)`.  Either you're doing something somewhere else to ensure that this won't ever fail at runtime, or you want some exception to be thrown at runtime in the event that the actual parameter passed to action is not an `ModelMapNode<T>`.

You can't do this by casting the `Action`, because the compiler knows it's not safe, but what you can do is create a new wrapper function that casts the parameter and then calls the other action:

```
public void AddAction<T>(Action<ModelMapNode<T>> childConfigurer)
{
    this.ActionOne = node => childConfigurer((ModelMapNode<T>)node);
}
```

Comment: Another possibility could be: `public class Class1
{
    private List<Delegate> Actions { get; set; }

    public void AddAction<T>(Action<ModelMapNode<T>> childConfigurer)
    {
        this.Actions.Add(childConfigurer);
    }
}`. Not sure what such a list is good for in either case.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Personally, given that the OP has stated Oded's solution isn't an option, I wouldn't really want to comment on what the "best" approach is without knowing the details of the OP's situation.  If we knew more, we could either verify that something like this is unfortunate, but still the best option, or provide a better option.

Answer (score 2):

That's fundamentally unsafe.
Had that been legal, you would be able to pass an `Action<ModelMapNode<SomeClass>>`, then cast it to `Action<ModelMapNode>` and pass it an incorrect class that it can't handle.

Instead, you should make the entire class generic, then change the field to an `Action<ModelMapNode<T>>`.

Comment: It is not possible, I'll change my question to get closest to you to understand the real case. PS: I know, its unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

The generic type `Action<in T>` is **contravariant** ("`in`") in its type argument `T`.

So you could say:

```
Action<ModelMapNode> a1 = XXX;
Action<ModelMapNode<T>> a2 = a1;
```

and it would work fine. Because if an action `a1` can take in *any* `ModelMapNode` then in particular it can tak in a `ModelMapNode<T>` because any `ModelMapNode<>` is a `ModelMapNode` by inheritance (base class).

You are trying to use `Action<in T>` as if it were **covariant**, not **contravariant**, and that can never work.

Comment: "and that can never work" That's not quite right.  The compiler cannot guarantee that it will always work.  It can sometimes work, and sometimes it won't.  Much like you can always implicitly upcast, but downcasts need to be explicit because they might not work.  The OP is saying that, even though the compiler can't guarantee it will work, he knows better, and knows that it will always work.  It's also different from, say, casting a string to an int, in which there is no possible way for it to ever work.

Comment: @Servy While I know what you mean, it is not too helpful. The asker has made the eqivalent of `public void AddObject(object obj) { this.StringList.Add((string)obj); }`. I am trying to make him realize that is bad. Sure the cast can go well in theory, but the design is logically flawed.

Comment: I agree entirely that it's generally a bad idea.  I can think of one or two exceptions, although without seeing the context we can't really tell if the context the OP is in is a valid exception.  Either way, his comments indicate he is aware of the consequences of what he's asking for.